# Utilizing the Strategy Pattern to Process Different Message Types

Tags: c#, interface, strategy-pattern

I have a log file with multiple different message types. Each message type is differentiated by tag 35. For example, tag 35 can equal 'i','s','g','p', etc. Each tag corresponds to a different type of message. For instance, tag 35='i' corresponds to a QuoteMessage, while 35='g' corresponds to a NewOrderMessage.

What I'd like to have is one function called

```
public class MessageProcessor
{

private readonly IEnumerable<ICommand> _commands;

public List<IMessage> ProcessMessageByType(MessageType type);
    var command = _commands.Where(c => (char)type == c.Type).First();
    return command.Do(); // Returns a list of messages of this type.
}
```

```
public interface ICommand
{
   string RegexMatch { get; set; }
   bool IsMatch(string input);
   List<IMessage> Do();
}

public class ProcessTagICommand : ICommand
{
   public string RegexMatch = "i";
   bool IsMatch(string input) => Regex.Match(input, RegexMatch).Success;
   List<IMessage> Do()
   {
      return // a list of quoteMessages. This won't compile :'(
   }
}
```

The issue I've run into is that for each message I need to return a different type of IMessage, which do not implicitly cast to type IMessage, even though they implement it's interface. For example, a QuoteMessage might be:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteMessage : IMessage
{

}

public class OrderMessage : IMessage
{

}
```

From `command.Do()` above, I'd return a `List<QuoteMessage>` which, for some reason, cannot be converted to an `IMessage` even though it implements its interface.

Can someone explain to me the best way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest response is use `IEnumerable`:

```
public interface ICommand
{

   IEnumerable<IMessage> Do();
}

public class ProcessTagICommand : ICommand
{

   public IEnumerable<IMessage> Do()
   {
      return new List<QuoteMessage>();
   }
}
```

This is becouse `IEnumerable` allows to set a covariant type as `IMessage`, yo can learn more about covariace and contravariance in dotnet: [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)